# How to use ScrollView with one RelativeLayout and two LinearLayout?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have implemented a `ScrollView` in which i have added a `RelativeLayout`. In this `RelativeLayout` a have added two `LinearLayout`. Each of this contains a `TextView` and a `ListView`. Each `ListView` contains over 25 items. I want to display all the items of both list views and have a single scroll for both. Now, if i add in the first `ListView` only 3 items and in the second 25, the first one gets no scroll and only the second gets a scroll. If i add in the first `ListView` 25 items and in the second 3, the first one gets a scroll and the second is not even displayed. How can i do that? Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

            <TextView
                android:text="title1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/productsToBuyTitle" />

            <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dragSortList1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1">

            <TextView
                android:text="title2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/allProductsTitle" />

            <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dragSortList2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just guessing. Did you try to pack all items in the same DTO? You can pass that DTO (with 28 items) to the one single scroll view.

Comment: your question is quite difficult to understand.. so can you provide me the picture for example..?

Comment: @EliasMP I need to have 2 different list views.

Comment: @Shivam All i want, is to have both items from both list views displyed with a single scroll.

Comment: Can you try using recycler view instead of DragSortListViewand check whethre its working?

Comment: No, i did not, beacause i need to use DragSortListView. And this is because in the back are bunch of stuff regardind the drag and drop.

Comment: @Shivam Yes. [Here](http://gogo.ro/alex/1.PNG) is a screens shot when the activity statrs and as you see [here](http://gogo.ro/alex/2.PNG), i got a scroll only to the second `ListView`. I need a single scroll to both list views.

Comment: you cannot add ScrollView or ScrollView type item under a parent ScrollView..!!

Comment: @Shivam I did not. I have only one `ScrollView` as you see in my code. I need the scroll for the entire RelativeLayout. I need to scroll over both list views.

Comment: `com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView` this listView contains the auto Scroll Property according to the item added into it..

Comment: check my answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

        <TextView
            android:text="title1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/productsToBuyTitle" />

        <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dragSortList1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="title2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/allProductsTitle" />

        <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dragSortList2" />
     </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks but i got an error. If i use `android:layout_height="0dp"` i got this: `Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_width`

Comment: have you set orientation of linearlayout.

Comment: with this layout the layout screen looks like this http://i.imgur.com/9ne4Yqs.png .Here two listviews are there with their individual scrolling.

Comment: Ok, and what can i do to have a single scroll for both list views? [Here](http://gogo.ro/alex/1.PNG) is a screens shot when the activity statrs and as you see [here](http://gogo.ro/alex/2.PNG), i got a scroll only to the second ListView. I need the scrool for th entire RelativeLayout.

Comment: the first listview did not get the scrollview as it has just 3 items .Try to add 25 items in that listview also.

Answer (score 0):

i HAVE DIVIDEN the screen into two part equally.. hope it will be scrolled now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

            <TextView
                android:text="title1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/productsToBuyTitle" />

            <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dragSortList1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1">

            <TextView
                android:text="title2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/allProductsTitle" />

            <com.example.alexm.shoppinglist.dlv.DragSortListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dragSortList2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: image is not opening please resend it

Comment: Please try again. There is a new space between the list views.

Comment: I need something like [this](http://gogo.ro/alex/4.PNG). Hope you undertstand me. A single scroll for the entire layout.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Comment: Shivam do you any other idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127774/discussion-between-shivam-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what would be better, not only in terms of scroll, but also considering performance, would be to have a SINGLE listview that inflates all those layouts. You would only have a single scroll to deal with and your performance would also be improved; nested listview with scrollview is not a good idea and the scroll can get tricky and, this way, your listview would only load visible cells (yay, even better performance).

So, you would define a ListView in that layout and use the adapter to inflate each of those views (the TextView and the list content, that is, the cells).

I believe that solves your problem. If you need the code, let me know, I'll update the answer

Comment: Ty for your answer but i really need both listviews because in the first are displayed some items from a DB and in the second are displayed others. I need to see both listviews completely with a single scroll for the entire layout. All i need is [this](gogo.ro/alex/4.PNG) in stead of [this](gogo.ro/alex/2.PNG) How can i do that?
If i set `android:layout_height="1000dp"` for both LinearLayout in stead of `wrap_content` it works fine. There is much of white space but i get a single scroll. I think `wrap_content` does not work fine.
Considering performance, ok, but is there another way?

Comment: If you are using API 21+ (Lollipop and above), you can use a NestedScrollView and, inside it, both ListViews and then use the attribute`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` or `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` for both ListViews, that should disable their scroll and make only the NestedScrollView scroll work. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes Fabio, i'm using API 21+. So, i changed the `ScrollView` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and set for each one of the ListView `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` and i have the same issue. I cannot understand why :( Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `fillViewPort` attribute? And the problem persists when using `wrap_content` or setting a fix height?

Comment: When i remove the `fillViewPort` attribute, in each ListView remains only one item. What is wired in stead, is that i can scroll in every ListView.. [This](http://gogo.ro/alex/5.PNG) is a screenshot for the first ListView and [this](http://gogo.ro/alex/6.PNG) is for the second ListView. What can be done?

Comment: If i use a fixed height (for each ListView), which is greater than the maximum height of the ListView, i get some white space and a single scroll for the entire layout. But i don't know how many items will be in the first ListView or in the other. If a ListView gets more items and the height will be less that i have set, than the scroll will appear again :|
I have tried to use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` with the simple `ScrollView` and same result!

Comment: But you should use a `NestedScrollView` and the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` should be used on the LISTVIEWS and not on the SCROLLVIEW. You want to set those attributes in the xml or in the activity, doing something like `listview1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` and `listview2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. Your `DragSortListView` extends ListView, right? Also, for debugging purposes, have you tried using a single ListView to check if the behavior is correct? If the behavior is wrong with a single one, then the problem is probably related to the ScrollView or something else

Comment: When i said that i tried to use simple `ScrollView` i set that attribute on the ListView not on the ScrollView, exactly how i did with the DragSortListView.  Yes, DragSortListView extends ListView. And yes i tried with a single ListView and it's behavior is correct. When i use 2 ListView, i get this issue.